# Looking for an example of a dynamically created Spark.DataGrid in Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder4.5

I'm trying to create a DataGrid dynamically in Flash Builder AS3 code (not in the markup) but can't get any data to display.
Here's how I'm created the grid:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < numOfWinners; i++){
            if (list[i].Name[0])                        
                dataP.addItem({profilePic: list[i].ProfilePicUrl.toString(), name: list[i].Name.toString(), prizePic: list[i].ItemImageUrl.toString()});
            else
                dataP.addItem({profilePic: list[i].ProfilePicUrl.toString(), name: list[i].UserName.toString(), prizePic: list[i].ItemImageUrl.toString()});
        }

        // Create a new DataGridColumn object.
        var playerCol:GridColumn = new GridColumn("profilePic");
        playerCol.width = 110;

        var nameCol:GridColumn = new GridColumn("name");
        nameCol.width = 100;             
        nameCol.itemRendererFunction = MyCustomItemRendererFunction;            
        var prizePicCol:GridColumn = new GridColumn("prizePic");
        prizePicCol.width = 160;

        cols.addItem(nameCol);
        cols.addItem(playerCol);
        cols.addItem(prizePicCol);
        grid.columns = cols;            
        grid.dataProvider = dataP;



        private function MyCustomItemRendererFunction(item:Object, column:GridColumn):ClassFactory 
    {           
        // Create a Class Factory variable
        var myRendererObject:ClassFactory;

        // This is the "default" color is nothing else happens
        // I'm passing it a pointer to "MyItemRenderer"

        myRendererObject = new ClassFactory(ProfilePicRenderer);

        if (column.dataField == "profilePic")
        {
            myRendererObject.properties = { source: item.profilePic};
        }

        return myRendererObject;

    }
```

All the examples I seem to find are in the markup for a Flex 4 (MX + Spark) project.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please specify what does "can't get any data to display" mean ? Is the grid and the columns visible ? Do you see your itemrenderers but they are empty? If so, please post the code of your ProfilePicRenderer. What i already can tell is that you should just override the set data() method in your item renderer and get the profile pic there instead of setting it via properties - this is what set data is for :)

Comment: I don't see anything. Just a blank space. The itemRendererFunction never gets called. I have a break point but it doesn't get hit.

Comment: Since I don't see it in your code I have to ask - you do add the datagrid to the stage with addChild(grid), right? And you don't set it to visible = false at some point or something?

Comment: correct. It seems this may not be supported in a pure AS project without Flex MX/Spark

Comment: But generally there is a way to use datagrids without Flex. Have you seen this? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa8.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add **ProfilePicRenderer** as below:

```
var playerCol:GridColumn = new GridColumn("Profile Picture");
var profilePicItemRenderer:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(ProfilePicRenderer);
playerCol.itemRenderer =  profilePicItemRenderer;
playerCol.width = 110;
```

where **ProfilePicRenderer.mxml** looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    override public function set data(value:Object):void {
        if (super.data != value) {
            super.data = value;
        }
        image.source = "./images/" + data.profilePic;
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>
<s:Image id="image" width="50" height="50"/>

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Similarly add **PrizePicRenderer** as below:

```
var prizePicCol:GridColumn = new GridColumn("Prize Picture");
var prizePicRenderer:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(PrizePicRenderer);
prizePicCol.itemRenderer =  prizePicRenderer;
prizePicCol.width = 160;
```

where **PrizePicRenderer.mxml** looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    override public function set data(value:Object):void {
        if (super.data != value) {
            super.data = value;
        }
        image.source = "./images/" + data.prizePic;
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>
<s:Image id="image" width="50" height="50"/>
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Here is the sample application which adds the `DataGrid` dynamically with `itemRenderer`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.collections.ArrayList;

    import spark.components.DataGrid;
    import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;

    private var dataP:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {"name": "Lebron James", "profilePic": "p1.jpeg", "prizePic": "t1.jpg"},
        {"name": "Stephen Curry", "profilePic": "p2.jpeg", "prizePic": "t2.jpg"},
        {"name": "Kevin Durant", "profilePic": "p3.jpeg", "prizePic": "t3.jpg"},]) ;

    private function addDataGrid():void
    {
        var grid:DataGrid = new DataGrid();

        var nameCol:GridColumn = new GridColumn("Name");
        nameCol.width = 100;
        nameCol.dataField = "name";

        var playerCol:GridColumn = new GridColumn("Profile Picture");
        var profilePicItemRenderer:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(ProfilePicRenderer);
        playerCol.itemRenderer =  profilePicItemRenderer;
        playerCol.width = 110;

        var prizePicCol:GridColumn = new GridColumn("Prize Picture");
        var prizePicRenderer:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(PrizePicRenderer);
        prizePicCol.itemRenderer =  prizePicRenderer;
        prizePicCol.width = 160;

        var cols:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
        cols.addItem(nameCol);
        cols.addItem(playerCol);
        cols.addItem(prizePicCol);
        grid.columns = cols;

        grid.dataProvider = dataP;
        vGroup.addElement(grid);
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>
<s:VGroup id="vGroup" paddingTop="10" paddingLeft="10"
                    paddingBottom="10" paddingRight="10">
    <s:Button label="Click to build DataGrid dynamically." click="addDataGrid()"/>
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

I assume you have picture files in your project and `dataProvider` is well defined. Hope this is helpful.

Here is the **ActionScript** version of **ProfilePicRenderer** which is `ProfilePicRendererAS.as` if you don't want **MXML**.

```
package {
import spark.components.Image;
import spark.components.gridClasses.GridItemRenderer;

public class ProfilePicRendererAS extends GridItemRenderer {
private var image:Image;
public function ProfilePicRendererAS() {
    super();
    image = new Image();
    image.width = 50;
    image.height = 50;
    this.addElement(image);
}
override public function set data(value:Object):void {
    if (super.data != value) {
        super.data = value;
    }
    image.source = "./images/" + data.profilePic;
}
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried it out and I'm getting a null reference from somewhere. It gets thrown vGroup.addElement. vGroup is not null. Here's the top of the stack:
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at mx.styles::StyleManager$/getStyleManager()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\styles\StyleManager.as:139]

Comment: I should also mention that I'm doing the whole app in AS3. We're not using MXML.

Comment: I've provided AS3 version of ProfilePicRenderer.mxml. Similarly you can write AS3 version of PrizePicRenderer.mxml.

Comment: Any idea what the exception would be from? Do I need to create a style manager or something?

Comment: It's working fine for me without error. I'm using Flex SDK 4.6 version.Which version of SDK you are using?

Comment: You got the above error when you run my sample application or you tried to implement the same in your application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111676/discussion-between-gbdcool-and-jbassking10).